# Entity Framework queries miss filtered index WHERE BIT field = 0

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, t-sql, linq-to-entities

I've noticed that Entity Framework translates LINQ queries with negative boolean filters such that the generated query plan won't use a filtered index. For example, the query:

```
context.Foo.Count(f => !f.IsActive)
```

generates the SQL statement:

```
SELECT 
    [GroupBy1].[A1] AS [C1]
    FROM ( SELECT 
        COUNT(1) AS [A1]
        FROM [dbo].[Foos] AS [Extent1]
        WHERE [Extent1].[IsActive] <> cast(1 as bit)
    )  AS [GroupBy1]
```

Notice the `WHERE` clause uses `[IsActive] <> cast(1 as bit)`, rather than the more intuitive `[IsActive] = 0`. This becomes an issue when using filtered indexes. The plan for the above query will not use the following index:

```
CREATE INDEX IX_Foo_IsActive ON Foos (IsActive) WHERE (IsActive = 0)
```

I suspect the reason that EF generates queries this way has something to do with DB null semantics, but this happens even with non-nullable bit fields. I've verified that writing the filtered index with EF's syntax (`IsActive <> 1`) fixes the issue, but that would break any non-EF queries using the more common syntax.

Is there a better work around?

Full example program here: http://dotnetfiddle.net/3kZugt. The entity type used above is:

```
public class Foo
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: FYI, This is now an open issue at CodePlex: https://entityframework.codeplex.com/workitem/2629

Comment: FYI, Ths is now an open issue at CodePlex: https://entityframework.codeplex.com/workitem/2629

Comment: Issue at github (marked as won't fix for some reason): https://github.com/dotnet/ef6/issues/562

Comment: This issue is finally fixed in EF core 6: https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/26764

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's not unusual that for some strange reason, sometimes we don't see something which is really obvious: do a direct translation of your DB predicate to a C# predicate, i.e.

```
WHERE IsActive = 0
```

is translated to

```
f => f.IsActive = false
```

You have to stop thinking in C# and start thinking in SQL ;)

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. My LINQ query above is `f => !f.IsActive`. You're saying that if I changed it to `f => f.IsActive == false`, EF would translate it differently?

Comment: Yep! That's right. I checked it so I can assure it does the desired `WHERE 0 = [Extent1].[IsActive]` on the DB side. And, although I have not tested it, if you write `f => f.IsActive != true` will surely translate to `WHERE 1 <> [Extent1].[IsActive]`. You usually wouldn't write it that way in C#... but EF makes a literal transaltion (Tested with EF5/ SQL Server). Surprising, isn't it?

Comment: Well that's bizarre-- but indeed it works (just tested on EF 6). Seems like this should be a bug; I can't think of any reason why the behavior should be different.

Comment: In fact there is an explanation for this: L2E parses the expression trees of the lambdas and trasnlates them literally to SQL if possible. So the expression tree `f.IsActive = false` is transalated literally to `0 = IsActive`. And your original expression, `f => !f.IsActive` doesn't have a direct translation to the db, so the tree is manipulated before converting it to SQL. I suppose it internally must convert the expression tree of `f => !f.IsActive` to `f => true != f.IsActive` to be able to convert it to SQL. And believe me, this is the most bizarre of it all.

Comment: LINQ-to-SQL actually mangles the translation so `f => f.IsActive == false` is actually generated as `WHERE (NOT (IsActive = 1))`. While this is logically equivalent when IsActive is type BIT, the SQL Server optimizer does not treat it as equivalent, so you get an unexpected query plan that can be orders of magnitude less efficient. I would classify that as a bug.

Comment: This behavior still exists in EF Core, and was also in Linq2SQL

Comment: @Suncat2000 We agree that `IsActive = 0` and `NOT (ISActive = 1)` are functionally equivalent. But the second part: "you get an unexpected query plan that can be orders of magnitude less efficient". Or more efficient: it depends on the data in the table., on which is the most selective value. So, depending on the data in the table, one or the other can be more selective, and thus, more "efficient". If you have such a deep knowledge of your DB, just write your own query and map it to an entity. Not a sinlge existing ORM is capable of optmizing. Sometimes, you need to do write your own queries.

Comment: This issue is finally fixed in EF core 6: https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/26764#issuecomment-974266534